# how to open nyroModal inside a modal?

Tags: background, modal-dialog, overlay, screenshot

The question: I have a Modal with Bootstrap so when I click on it, of course, it opens the page with some info.

On that page, I have a few images. I have tried, when you click the image it will load the image with a black background and (shadowbox style). The thing is that when I tried that it always load the image at the background, not in front and I want to keep the modal opened because you won't be opening the modal 100 times to see the 100 images.

I'm using bootstrap and nyroModal

Comment: add `z-index` to image or the div in which the image is, bootstrap modal default `z-index` is `1050` when shown so image `z-index` should be higher

Comment: Thanks for the useful information! its working now :) thanks !